# Where in my code are duplicates being deleted?

Tags: python, permutation

An important part of my output is being able to identify the length of the `finalList` but somewhere in my code, duplicates are being deleted and I can't figure out where

```
from itertools import chain, permutations
allPos = []
first_list = ['a','b','c']
match_list = [['a','b','c'], ['a','b','c']]

for i in range(1,30):
    for phrase in permutations(first_list, i):
        for ind, letter in enumerate(chain.from_iterable(phrase)):
             if ind >= len(match_list) or letter not in match_list[ind]:
                break
        else:
            allPos.append(phrase)

finalList = []

for i in allPos:
    if len(i) == len(allPos[-1]):
        finalList.append(i)

print(finalList)
```

OUTPUT

```
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b')]
```

I know that it is deleting duplicates, or perhaps my code is just missing something completely because I am missing `[('a','a'), ('b','b'), ('c','c')]` from my output

Comment: Here: [`permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)?

Comment: is your else block supposed to be indented?

Comment: I have read the docs @zvone

Comment: yes it is supposed to be indented @kpie

Comment: My point was that function `permutations` does not return duplicates.

Comment: Ah I see, is there a replacement that does allow duplicates? does products() fill this place? if so, what is the syntax? @zvone

Comment: if your lists are as you show in this example, after `permutations` you can add a new list using this line `list(zip(*match_list))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this. Change `iterable` using permutations.

```
from itertools import chain, permutations
...
...
for i in range(1,30):
    # change iterable
    for phrase in permutations([j for ele in match_list for j in ele], i):

...
for i in set(allPos):
    if len(i) == len(allPos[-1]):
        finalList.append(i)

print (sorted(finalList))
[('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b'), ('c', 'c')]
```